# Night Web Browser By Alex - Stalled

Tags: ipad

I'm using the app Night Web Browser By Alex and I'm stuck on the bookmarks page.  Any ideas how to get out of it? I'm on an  IPAD

Comment: This is more of a support request.

Comment: The lack of details make this unlikely to get many votes, but support alone isn't a bad thing when the question provides enough detail for someone to proffer a decent answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a iPad version and some bug fixes for the iPhone version. The iPad version is almost ready so this is a known bug of the app.